# JQuery ui dialog css problem under Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, dialog

I got a job : There is a website, that is contains some ExtJ functions. I have to change these to JQuery functions.

I'm started to change dialogs. Under IE8 / IE7 it works fine, but under FF 3.5.10 it's not perfect.

The code I'm using is :

```
<div id="dialog-lostpassword" title="Elfelejtett jelszó">
  <p class="validateTips">Kérjük adja meg az e-mail címét:</p>

  <form>
      <fieldset>
        <label for="dialog_lostpassword_email">E-mail:</label>
        <input type="text" name="dialog_lostpassword_email" id="dialog_lostpassword_email" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
      </fieldset>

      <div align = 'center'>
        Ha Ön még nem rendelkezik hozzáféréssel, <a href = '../regisztracio.op'>itt regisztrálhat</a>!
        Elfelejtette jelszavát? <a href="javascript:showLostPasswordWindow();" >Ide kattintva</a> igényelhet újat!
      </div>

    </form>
</div>
```

The Javascript:

```
function showLostPasswordWindow() {
    $('#dialog-lostpassword').dialog('open');
};

$(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog("destroy");

    var dialog_lostpassword_email = $("#dialog_lostpassword_email"),
        allFields = $([]).add(dialog_lostpassword_email),
        tips = $(".validateTips");

    function updateTips(t) {
        tips
            .text(t)
            .addClass('ui-state-highlight');
        setTimeout(function() {
            tips.removeClass('ui-state-highlight', 1500);
        }, 500);
    }

    function checkLength(o,n,min,max) {

        if ( o.val().length > max || o.val().length < min ) {
            o.addClass('ui-state-error');
            updateTips("Az e-mail cím hossza " + min + " és " + max + " között kell legyen" + ".");
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }

    }

    function checkRegexp(o,regexp,n) {

        if ( !( regexp.test( o.val() ) ) ) {
            o.addClass('ui-state-error');
            updateTips(n);
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }

    }

    $("#dialog-lostpassword").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 250,
        width: 380,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            'Küldés': function() {
                var bValid = true;
                allFields.removeClass('ui-state-error');

                bValid = bValid && checkLength(dialog_lostpassword_email,"",6,80);
                bValid = bValid && checkRegexp(dialog_lostpassword_email,/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i,"Hibás az e-mail cím formátuma.");

                if (bValid) {
                    // ha 'Küldés' gombra kattintotunk és valid minden
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            },
            'Mégsem': function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        },
        close: function() {
            allFields.val('').removeClass('ui-state-error');
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is :

In FF when I call showLostPasswordWindow() function the dialog shows up, but it is empty, doesn't contains the input field and the texts. Input field and texts are in the background, they are part of the main site (they are at the top of the page).

Comment: Sry Pointy, was making the same edits you were at the same time, lol

Comment: Is there any particular reason for the dialog markup to contain that `<form>` block?  Is it possible that there's another outer form surrounding it?  I'm just guessing, because I don't see anything in that markup or code that seems like it could cause that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm...you could try using Firebug console to check for js console errors, and also to look at the markup and see what's going on.

Comment: Thank you guys. The <form> block was the reason. I commented out, now it's working under FF too.

Thanky you very much ! ;)

Comment: Glad you found it, funny how jQuery is so simple...but yet sometimes it takes a while to get it working right.